# Spring Boot app cannot connect to Redis Replica in Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, redis, lettuce

I am experiencing a weird issue with Redis connectivity in the Docker.
I have a simple Spring Boot application with a Master-Replica configuration.
As well as docker-compose config which I use to start Redis Master and Redis Replica.

If I start Redis via docker-compose and Spring Boot app as a simple java process outside of Docker, everything works fine. It can successfully connect to both Master and Replica via localhost.

If I launch Spring Boot app as a Docker container alongside Redis containers it can successfully connect to Master, but not Replica. Which means that I can write and read to Master node but when I try to read from Replica I get the following error:

```
redis-sample-app_1  | Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: redis-replica-a/172.31.0.2:7001
redis-sample-app_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
redis-sample-app_1  |   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
```

In the redis.conf I've changed the following to bind it to all network interfaces:

```
bind * -::*
protected-mode no
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  redis-master:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server --include /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    volumes:
      - ./conf/redis-master.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  redis-replica-a:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server --include /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    volumes:
      - ./conf/redis-replica.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "7001:6379"

  redis-sample-app:
    image: docker.io/library/redis-sample:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    environment:
      - SPRING_REDIS_HOST=redis-master
      - SPRING_REDIS_PORT=6379
      - SPRING_REDIS_REPLICAS=redis-replica-a:7001
    ports:
      - "9080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
      - redis-replica-a
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  redis:
    port: 6379
    host: localhost
    replicas: localhost:7001
```

RedisConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
class RedisConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.redis.replicas:}")
    private String replicasProperty;

    private final RedisProperties redisProperties;

    public RedisConfig(RedisProperties redisProperties) {
        this.redisProperties = redisProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public StringRedisTemplate masterReplicaRedisTemplate(LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory masterReplicaLettuceConnectionFactory(LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceConfig) {
        LOG.info("Master: {}:{}", redisProperties.getHost(), redisProperties.getPort());
        LOG.info("Replica property: {}", replicasProperty);

        RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration configuration = new RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration(redisProperties.getHost(), redisProperties.getPort());

        if (StringUtils.hasText(replicasProperty)) {
            List<RedisURI> replicas = Arrays.stream(this.replicasProperty.split(",")).map(this::toRedisURI).collect(Collectors.toList());
            LOG.info("Replica nodes: {}", replicas);
            replicas.forEach(replica -> configuration.addNode(replica.getHost(), replica.getPort()));
        }

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(configuration, lettuceConfig);
    }

    @Scope("prototype")
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    ClientResources clientResources() {
        return DefaultClientResources.create();
    }

    @Scope("prototype")
    @Bean
    LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceConfig(ClientResources dcr) {
        ClientOptions options = ClientOptions.builder()
                .timeoutOptions(TimeoutOptions.builder().fixedTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)).build())
                .disconnectedBehavior(ClientOptions.DisconnectedBehavior.REJECT_COMMANDS)
                .autoReconnect(true)
                .build();

        return LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED)
                .clientOptions(options)
                .clientResources(dcr)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        return new StringRedisTemplate(redisConnectionFactory);
    }

    private RedisURI toRedisURI(String url) {
        String[] split = url.split(":");
        String host = split[0];
        int port;
        if (split.length > 1) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        } else {
            port = 6379;
        }
        return RedisURI.create(host, port);
    }
}
```

Please advise how to continue with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running everything (redis, replica and spring) inside the docker network you should be using port `6379` instead of `7001`

`7001` port can be used to connect from outside the container to it. But now you are trying to connect from container to container.

So change your environment variable to

```
SPRING_REDIS_REPLICAS=redis-replica-a:6379
```

Comment: I pass these parameters in the docker-compose file, otherwise, it will be connecting to localhost, but, as you can see from the error it is trying to connect to redis-replica-a/172.31.0.2:7001
    environment:
      - SPRING_REDIS_HOST=redis-master
      - SPRING_REDIS_PORT=6379
      - SPRING_REDIS_REPLICAS=redis-replica-a:7001

Comment: @endryha you are right, I have not properly read environment variables, my fault. Try using `SPRING_REDIS_REPLICAS=redis-replica-a:6379` . 7001 is the port to connect from outside to the container. Inside the network, port 6379 is used.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the fun thing is that I know that but was completely blind with the issue, thanks a lot, just needed a separate pair of eyes

Comment: Could you please update your answer so I can accept it?